# Is there more than one way to define this function?

Tags: scala

Now I'm reading [next](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) book about Scala and found some exercises for self-evaluation.

Page 27, exercise 2.7:

> Let's look at another example, currying, which converts a finction f of two arguments into a function of one argument that partially applies f. Here again there's only one implementation that compiles. Write this implementation

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = ...
```

It's really important to mention, that exercise says about only **one possible** implementation, that compiles. If book mean that there is physically only one option, then I don't understand why the book says there is only one solution.

For example, [solution](https://github.com/scala-exercises/exercises-fpinscala/blob/main/src/main/scala/fpinscalalib/GettingStartedWithFPSection.scala) from book:

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = a => b => f(a,b)
```

And my own one:

```
 def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = a => f(a, _)
```

Both variants were successfully compiled. So,let me introduce my vision of solution:

Let's imagine next [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory):

[image]

1. `f` - morphism which defined via `f: (A, B) → C`
2. `g` - morphism which defined via `g: B → C`
3. `l` - morphism which defined via `l: A → C`

As I understand such category, we have next expression for function **output**:

```
A → (B → C) = A → C
```

Such transition can be done because of composition property of category. And that's why I'm used more short expression for `A → (B → C` as `a => f(a, _)`.

Do I understand it correct?

Comment: Your solution and the one of the book are the same, you're just using syntactic sugar (`_`) but if you desugarize it's strictly the same.

Comment: `f(a, _)` is just syntactic sugar for `b => f(a, b)`. So it's not really a different implementation. It's the same implementation with a shorter syntax.

Comment: Ok, it's syntactic sugar, but anyway, such short transition (A => C) proofed by composition and associativity properties and exists as unique morphism.

Comment: (1) It seems that you might be interested in a detailed discussion of the difference between currying and partial application: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867210/is-there-a-mathematical-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application/2022635#2022635). The difference is subtle, not exactly easily digestible if all examples that you have come from basic functional programming. But maybe your intuition is pointing to something: namely that there is indeed a difference between currying and partial application.

Comment: (2) (contd.) Applied to your example, in simple terms: "There are categories where the partial application `f(a, _)` can be defined, but in which `b => f(a, b)` is not a thing."